# Is it possible to not reset an enhanced SvelteKit form after successful submit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have the following enhanced SvelteKit form:

```html
<script>
  import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
</script>

<form method="POST" use:enhance>
  <input name="name" />
</form>
```

When it is submitted successfully the form is reset. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can customize the behavior of the `enhance` action further by providing it a [`submit function`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-submitfunction). This function in turn can return a callback that is called when the form has been submitted.

The `update` property in the first parameter of this callback is a function that will trigger the logic that would be triggered if this callback wasn't set, and it takes an option `reset` which allows you to not reset the form after successful submit.

```html
<script>
  import { enhance } from '$app/forms';

  function handleSubmit() {
    // ...

    return async ({ update }) => {
      await update({ reset: false });
    };
  }
</script>

<form method="POST" use:enhance={handleSubmit}>
  <input name="name" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you (like me) want to have an action that works like `enhance` but that never resets the entered values in the `<form>`, I think you can use the following `customEnhance` that I just wrote for this specific purpose:

**custom-enhance.js**

```js
import { enhance } from '$app/forms';

export function customEnhance(form, submitFunction) {

    function customSubmitFunction() {
        return async (actionResult) => {
            await actionResult.update({reset: false})
            if(submitFunction){
                await submitFunction(actionResult)
            }
        }
    }

    return enhance(form, customSubmitFunction)

}
```

**+page.svelte**

```html
<script>
import { customEnhance } from './custom-enhance'
</script>
<form method="POST" use:customEnhance>
   <!-- Does never reset form values, but does otherwise work like "enhance". -->
   ...
</form>
```

I haven't tested it much yet, so no guarantees I got the implementation right, but works good for me so far :)